# Publicar servicio soap en servidor

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, soap, tomcat

He desarrollado un servicio en Java y lo público a través de un servidor virtual de la siguiente manera:

`Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:2021/soap/Persona", new ServiceImpl());`

Cuando ejecuto el código, el servicio se publica en la dirección y puerto que he indicado en la instrucción anterior. En SoapUI importo el wsdl y puedo consumir las operaciones del servicio correctamente.

Lo que yo quiero hacer ahora es alojar mi servicio en un servidor para publicarlo de forma real y que pudiese acceder a él desde otra máquina. Entiendo que tengo que alojarlo en una servidor Tomcat, pero no se los pasos que tengo que seguir ni he encontrado mucha información al respecto. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias

Un saludo

---

Pero para desplegar tengo que convertirlo a proyecto web, ¿no?

Ahora mismo, mi servicio soap no está configurado como servicio, esta es su estructura:

[image: Estructura directorios servicio SOAP]

¿Necesito añadir web.xml? Por favor, necesitaría alguna instrucción más. Ahora mismo, no puedo generar war de mi servicio.

Saludos

Comment: en qué servidor deseas publicarlo? Servidor tradicional o en una nube como pcf?

Comment: Hola. Quiero publicarlo en un servidor tradicional, en Apache Tomcat

Comment: configura el puerto de tu tomcat y abre ese puerto en tu servidor, despliegas tu aplicación y con eso debería de bastar, muchos lo que hacen es publicarlo para 0.0.0.0 en vez de localhost, eso lo asocia con la interfaz de red local y como generalmente ya tienen configurado todo con eso basta para que se asocie con el dominio que tenga configurado el servidor. Si tienes un proveedor en particular tal ve alguien te pueda pasar más información en particular, pero con esto deberías de poder publicarlo en un servidor propio.

Comment: Pero mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo lo despliego en el servidor? ¿Necesito archivo web.xml? Es que estoy bastante perdido en ese sentido. Lo de abrir puertos ya me preocuparé luego, pero lo que necesito ahora mismo es que pueda desplegarlo y pueda acceder a él en local.

Comment: puede ser en el war o ear si lo quieres en un archivo o explotado. Sí... como normalmente haces el despliegue en tu local.